# Can't set 'touched' to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I just trying to create a custom Formik `<Field />`. It is a `<input type = file />`  with opacity=0 and depending of `values` i styling my `<Error />` component and `<input type = text />`. `values.photo` is ok. The problem is that touched never becoming true, so i can't show my `<Error />` component. Can you explain what goes wrong?
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-violet-qgxr3?file=/src/components/FileInput.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in your file input component just add this:

```
form.setTouched({...form.touched,[field.name]: true });
```

setTouched take object of fields and `field.name` is the file input name.

Comment: It works not proper, i added one more input to show it. I faced this problem before. When i called setTouched it overwrite all 'touched' object

Comment: if you have multiple input just pass form.touched with the object and assign the field you want check edited aswer.

Comment: Ah, can you show some code please? I'm new in Formic

Comment: I've tried to save object form.touched to local state and then to add to this object new property: [field.name]:true and pass it to setTouched. But it seems that in some moment form.touched became undefined and again i overwrite. It is so tricky for me

Comment: what do you mean save form.touched in local state ? you can access it from props .

Answer (score -2):

when you handle the file input by listening to onChange event.
As soon as that onChange method is called you can mark your field asTouched by calling
**.markAsTouched()** so that it would show the error if the condition in validated.

Comment: Are you sure that .markAsTouched() is a Formik function? I cant find it in the documentation.

Comment: That's not part of Formik